# awslogs no longer runs after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, log, do-release-upgrade

After the system was upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, it was no longer possible to upload logs to CloudWatch. The awslgs program did not generate the log `/var/log/awslogs.log`. How to check this problem?

```
$ sudo service awslogs status 
● awslogs.service - LSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent. 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/awslogs; generated) 
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-10-31 03:13:04 UTC; 43s ago 
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8) 
Process: 1926902 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/awslogs start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
CPU: 22ms

Oct 31 03:13:04 ip-systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent....   
Oct 31 03:13:04 ip-awslogs[1926908]: Starting system awslogs daemon 
Oct 31 03:13:04 ip-awslogs[1926910]: process already running. 
Oct 31 03:13:04 ip-awslogs[1926908]: * /var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh is running 
Oct 31 03:13:04 ip-systemd[1]: Started LSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent..
```